# Preventing fullscreen app from freezing while minimised

Tags: windows-8.1, fullscreen

Is there any option to keep a game (or program) running when minimising it from an exclusive fullscreen mode?

I'm streaming and when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of the window people see screen freeze and I want to prevent that.

Is there any simple way except using the windowed fullscreen mode? Windowed fullscreen results in a slight FPS drop. When streaming it's the difference between 80 and 50 fps, 50 is too low a framerate.

I'm running Windows 8.1.

Comment: What graphics card do you have?  Nvidia 660+, 700+ and 900+ series graphics cards have ShadowPlay and GameStreaming technologies which can record gameplay with nearly no performance drop at all.

Comment: Thank you for edit and help, but sadly I'm on notebook and my Nvidia is not allowed to use ShadowPlay. So I use OBS.